# Magento 2 integration with AWS Elasticsearch service

Tags: magento2, aws, elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect my Magento to AWS elasticsearch service but I can't get a successfull connection.

Magento is running on an AWS EC2 instance which the IP address is allowed on Elasticsearch access policy. ES is version 6.8, and Magento 2.3.1.

In

> stores configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search

I've tryed to configure it with the given endpoint in ES service admin panel on AWS, with ports `9200`, `9300`, `443`, `80` and could not connect

[image: Configuration example]

My Elasticsearch doesn't have an user and pass to set HTTP auth.

Does anyone have made this integration and can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Id suggest you take a look at this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configuring-elasticsearch-magento/ explains the process in detail

Comment: did you figure out a solution? i'm interested in setting that up as well

Comment: @Kris Wen, not yet. I stoped working on this but now I'm back, if I find something useful I'll let you know, please do the same!

Comment: @igor Thank you,Upon my researches yesterday. Seems like AWS Elasticsearch is not the best fit. https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/379

Comment: @igor by the way, i found it online that you can probably hosted elasticsearch engine using free plan from here. https://www.openshift.com/products/online/

Comment: Nice @KrisWen, thanks for the info! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the connection by making Nginx changes.
I created a configuration file for nginx to proxy messages to my AWS ES.

So in my /etc/nginx/conf.d/ a .conf file with the following content:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://myAwsElasticsearchServiceEndpoint.com;
    }
}
```

Then in

> "stores configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search"

I configured:

- Search Engine: Elasticsearch 6.0+
- Elasticsearch Server Hostname: https://myAwsElasticsearchServiceEndpoint.com
- Elasticsearch Server Port: 8080

A successfull connection was made, and running reindex I could comprove that data was sent to AWS ES.

If someone knows a better way or why this way is not good please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: not sure why you need to proxy external connection...

Answer (score 0):

My AWS Elasticsearch Cluster is in AWS VPC and so is my AWS EC2 Magento Instance.

The AWS Security Group has HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports allowed as Inbound Rules associated with the AWS Elasticsearch Cluster.

I used the following configurations:

- Search Engine: Elasticsearch 6.0+
- Elasticsearch Server Hostname: https://MyAWSElasticsearchServiceEndpoint.com
- Elasticsearch Server Port: 80

Comment: I can confirm using 2.3 and AWS elastic search 6.0 and deployed in the same VPC as the ec2 instance was successful with no need for a reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

I also wasn't able to connect to AWS Elasticsearch when Magento 2 runs at another hoster.

Using the described solution from [above](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291759/39426) worked, although the configuratio in Magento 2 backend is like this:

- Elasticsearch Server Hostname: `127.0.0.1` - it connects to your local server, do not put the AWS ES endpoint here
- ...

P.S.
For those asking why using a proxy is a good thing, [check Magento dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/es-config-nginx.html#es-ws-secure-nginx-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **AWS Elasticseach** service then try **443** port in **Magento Elasticsearch service settings**.

Answer (score 0):

Use port `443` and make sure you don't have a trailing slash on the hostname.

This fails:
`https://vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com/`

This succeeds:
`https://vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com`